# Wordpress: How do I avoid color distortion of uploaded images?

Tags: wordpress, colors

When uploading files to the Wordpress media library the colors are occasionally distorted. This is especially noticeable in the blue tones. I think it is due to a missing conversion of the color space.
Does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use this plugin to solve the problem: [Color Space Fixer](https://github.com/CreunaFI/color-space-fixer)